# How to user a svelte store variable in an endpoint?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, supabase, supabase-database

Im using supabase for my back end and in my end point i want to fetch data for the user that is logged in via the .eq method.

I have a user variable in my store however

I keep getting errors because i dont know how to get access to user and use it in the try catch.

Example

```
import {user} from .... 

export const get= async() = {

try{
Const {data} = await supabase.from('post').select('*').eq('id', $user.id)

   Return {
       Body:{
           data
            }
          }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nicholas! Are you using the javascript or typescript library here?